# How can I do this curl command on express.js/node.js?

Tags: node.js, curl, express

I want to convert this curl command and being able to do it using express.js

```
curl -L "http://example.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

well if you really need a curl equivalent you can try node-curl

```
npm install node-curl
```

you will probably need to add `libcurl4-gnutls-dev.`